# AWS, Beanstalk + Worker Tier + Cron and security in the Task URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, worker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am transforming my web app to adapt it to the way Beanstalk and Workers want me to define cron tasks:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks

I see I have to implement an **URL** that executes the Task.

It looks to me like a big security hole, anyone with knowledge of the *Task URL* will be able to invoke the task.

Which are the usual patterns to add some security wrapper to these *Task URLs*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going through the same thing while back. However if you look at docs you will see that it talks about following (except third point).

1. Make sure that URL only accepts request from localhost and IP.
2. Make the that URL only accepts POST requests
3. Last but not the least data should conform with whatever format you choose. I think JSON is default.

Since it only accepts request from localhost it is safe. If you want to implement extra security you can check for header as well to only allow certain agent.

Comment: I am adding a security step to these endpoints like `request.host == "localhost"`. But I have a concern: can I simulate that my laptop request is coming from `localhost` and cheat the server maybe with some `/etc/hosts` trick?

Comment: You can also add IP restrictions so that only localhost IP 127.0.0.1 is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply lock down the Security Group assigned to the Elastic Beanstalk worker tier environment so that it only accepts incoming requests from other EC2 instances in the worker tier. In other words, the Security Group should have a single inbound rule, with the source type "Custom" and the source value is the ID of the security group. Then you can be sure only the worker tier daemon can post to your worker tier task URL.

Comment: The problem is that the same code will be deployed to my production web app instances, and that ones must have public access.

Comment: The Security Group is an AWS network level setting. It's not a code change. So the code should be the same in each EB environment.

Comment: What I mean is that the Task URLs will be exposed also in my production servers (because the code is the same) and on that servers I can not constrict access.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying now. I really wouldn't want that URL exposed at all on non-worker servers. Can you change your server configuration somehow to only enable that endpoint based on an environment variable? Without knowing more about what programming language and server you are using I don't know how to recommend anything more specific.

Comment: I am testing the [@nicholasnet's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42095426/316700) I think the `Make sure that URL only accepts request from localhost` will make the trick